# Adding textfields works fine but removing textfields fails

Tags: jquery, html, textfield

I'm working on a jQuery add/remove textfields feature. Adding textfields works fine but removing textfields seems to be a problem.

```
$(function () {
    var json = {
        "welcomeList": ["Thanks for coming", "Please select from the following list", "dwadwadsds"],
            "endList": ["Press come again", "Press 0"]
    };

    $.each(json.welcomeList, function (_, vv) {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class=cnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="' + vv + '"placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo('#p_scents');
    });

    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function (event) {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + i + '" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').on('click', function () {
        alert("Hello 1");
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
             alert("Hello 3");
            i--;
        }
        alert("Hello 2");
        return false;
    });
});
```

I created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadm15/tZPg4/11043/) for the same. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating elements with the same ID's, and using event handlers that doesn't bind to the created elements, here's a much better way to do this

```
$(function () {
    var json = {
        "welcomeList": ["Thanks for coming", "Please select from the following list", "dwadwadsds"],
            "endList": ["Press come again", "Press 0"]
    }, i = 0;

    $.each(json.welcomeList, function (_, val) {
        $('#p_scents').append(createInput(++i, val));
    });

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#p_scents').append(createInput(++i), '');
    });

    function createInput(i, vv) {
        var p     = $('<p />'),
            label = $('<label />', {'for' : 'p_scnts' + i}),
            input = $('<input />', {
                type        : 'text', 
                'class'     : 'cnt', 
                size        : 20, 
                name        : 'p_scnt', 
                value       : vv,
                placeholder : 'Input Value'
            }),
            anchor = $('<a />', {
                href : '#', 
                id   : 'remScnt' + i,
                text : 'Remove',
                on   : {
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).closest('p').remove();
                    }
                }
            });

        return p.append(label.append(input), anchor);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tZPg4/11106/)

Answer (score 0):

regarding to the provided `fiddle` you are creating `<a>` tags with the same `id`= `remScnt` which is wrong and jquery can not recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use same id `remScnt` for remove button chance it to class and then change your remove code like this:-

```
 $(document).on('click','.remScnt',function (event) {        
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/tZPg4/11099/)

Comment: Hello Mohit, I saw your fiddle, but if you delete the contents of the already existing textields and remove them, it fails again

Answer (score 0):

first off, upon checking your fiddle code, you are setting the "remove" link with the same ID:

```
<a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a>
```

when you are using multiple instances of it on your page. I would suggest you use a class instead.

```
<a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a>
```

The reason why the remove script fails is that it doesn't know which parent the element you are trying to remove belongs. It's beter to use the following instead:

```
$(this).closest('p').remove();
```

secondly, and while this works on already existing elements, it wouldn't on newly added ones- so you better delegate the event.